# EXPECT_CALL for a mock function with argument of type unique_ptr reference

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

I want to unit test following function:

```
void
MyClass::add(const Shape& shape)
{
   std::unique_ptr< Line> line;
   if (m_DataBase.getLine(shape->getId(), line).ok())
   {
      addEntry(line->getDimensions());
   }
}
```

In order to do that I need to mock getLine function of the DataBase class:

```
class DataBase
{
 public:
   virtual Result getLine(const ShapeId& shapeId, const std::unique_ptr< Line >& line) = 0;
...
}
```

DataBase class mock:

```
class DataBaseMock
{
 public:
   MOCK_METHOD2(getLine, Result(const ShapeId& shapeId, const std::unique_ptr< Line >& line));
...
};
```

MyClass::add function test goes as follows:

```
MyClassTest::MyClassTest{
    DataBaseMock m_DataBaseMock;
    std::unique_ptr< MyClass> m_MyClass;
}

void MyClassTest::setUp(){
    m_MyClass = std::unique_ptr< MyClass >(new MyClass(m_DataBaseMock));
}

void MyClassTest::Test_Add()
{
   Shape shape;
   std::unique_ptr <Line> line = std::unique_ptr <Line> (new Line());

   EXPECT_CALL(m_DataBaseMock, getLine(_,_)).WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgReferee< 1 >(line), Return(Result::OK);
   CPPUNIT_ASSERT_NO_THROW(m_MyClass->add(shape));
}
```

While above code works when getLine function takes shared_ptr as parameter, in case of unique_ptr there is following error at EXPECT_CALL line:

```
error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = Line; _Dp = std::default_delete<Line>]'
    EXPECT_CALL(m_DataBaseMock, getLine(_,_)).WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgReferee< 1 >(line), Return(Result::OK);
```

Comment: If you want control on the return you should look at the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50958137/expect-call-for-a-mock-function-with-argument-of-type-unique-ptr-reference

Answer (score 5):

Solution consists of the trick, that is to delegate the `getLine()` method to a mock method (let’s call it `callGetLine()`) that does not take move-only `std::unique_ptr` parameter:

```
MOCK_METHOD2(callGetLine, Result(const ShapeId& shapeId, Line* line));
Result getLine(const ShapeId& shapeId, const std::unique_ptr< Line >& line) {
    return callGetLine(shapeId, line.get());
}
```

Note that there's no need to define or declare `callGetLine()` in a base class. You only need to define it as a `MOCK_METHOD` in the mock class.

Now you set expectation on the `callGetLine()` method.

```
EXPECT_CALL(m_DataBaseMock, callGetLine(_,NotNull()).WillOnce(Return(Result::OK));
```

Comment: It compiles ok but there is no control over Line returned by the arg of getLine function. As a result there is SEGFAULT at addEntry(...)

I tried to modify your EXPECT_CALL to add SetArgPointee:
EXPECT_CALL(m_DataBaseMock, callGetLine(_,_).WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgPointee< 1 >(line.get()), Return...

but it result in
gmock-actions.h:813:30: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Line' and 'Line* const')
     *::testing::get<N>(args) = value_;
Line.hpp:30:16: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Line* const' to 'const Line&'
at:
Line& operator=(const Line &rhs);

Comment: I do not see `addEntry` definition, sorry, I can not help more.

Comment: Problem is not within addEntry function. The problem is that getLine mock returns OK but line argument is not assigned valid reference. As a result addEntry operates on nullptr unique_ptr.
Anyway, thanks for help.